# move_uploaded_file error for new folder

Tags: php, file, file-upload, upload, server

I have a folder in my server where I am uploading file using a php script with the function move_uploaded_file. Now i have created another folder under the same directory and I want to do the same for it.

I have set all the permission to read , write and execute(777). But when I try to upload a file to the new folder it shows this error.

"move_uploaded_file(/var/www/html/HV/tag/human_wal_r.wav): failed to open stream: Permission denied"

I am posting my code here.

```
    <?php

// Path to move uploaded files

 //$target_path = "";

 if(isset($_FILES['fileUp']['name'])){

    $fileName= basename($_FILES['fileUp']['name']);



    $pieces = explode("_", $fileName);

    $testStr= $pieces[0];


    echo "pieces   ". $testStr;
    if($testStr=="human")
    {
        $target_path = "/var/www/html/HV/tag/";

    }
    else
    {
        $target_path = "/var/www/html/HV/uploads/";
    }

    $target_path = $target_path . basename($_FILES['fileUp']['name']);
    echo $target_path."\n";

    try
    {
        if (!move_uploaded_file($_FILES['fileUp']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
            // make error flag true

            echo basename($_FILES['fileUp']['tmp_name'])."   ";
            echo "The file ". $target_path;
            echo "error!!!!!!";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "successfully uploaded!!";
        }

    }catch(Exception $e) {
        // Exception occurred. Make error flag true
        echo "exception::  ";
        echo $e;
    }

 }
 else
 {
    echo "no";
 }


?>
```

Comment: add `error_reporting(E_ALL);ini_set('display_errors',1);` just after `<?php` and check for the complete errors. put those errors in your question.

Comment: I have edited the question now.

Answer (score 0):

Check this path permission /var/www/html/HV/nd/ , or check if this is a correct path because in your code I don't see any nd/ directory as target path

Comment: The path is correct. nd/ is a new folder that I am trying but still getting the same result. 

I checked the path permission and got this

drwxrwxrwx nd

Comment: this is what I get,

drwxrwxrwx nd
drwxrwxrwx tag
drwxrwxrwx uploads

So i donot think theres an issue with permission

Comment: yea permission looks okay for that, but maybe you need to give permission to the parent too? I don't know why you aren't allowed to write that file to that folder

Comment: yeah this is killing me. I have set 777 permission to its parent and as far as I can go up into hierarchy. But still no luck!! What bothers me most is I can write file to the "upload" folder without any issue which happens to be in the same directory.